# How to programmatically upload an Arduino sketch generated by node.js (electron) or from browser?

Tags: arduino-mega, uploading, compile, build, node.js

We are trying to make an app that generates an Arduino sketch (.ino) using Google's Blockly and node.js, and uploads it to Arduino.

Even after searching a lot, I am unable to find how to build and upload the generated code to the board. Is there any tool or API available for node.js to do the same?

Or could I call some binary for this function. Please help.

Comment: The tool for uploading to an Arduino is "avrdude", it's a command line application that Arduino uses in the background. I'm quote dure you can invoke/run it from nodejs

Comment: There is also `arduino-builder.exe` command line tool in Arduino IDE (since 1.6.6) so you can build and upload sketch programmatically.

Comment: Or you can install Sudar Muthu's [Arduino Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile) (package `arduino-mk` on Debian-bases OSes), then just `require("child_process").exec("make upload", callback);`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you need to do:

1. Compile the sketch into a .HEX file
2. Upload the sketch to the board

The first part can be done with `arduino-builder` which is part of the IDE since 1.6.6, or you can use one of various `Makefile` projects on a platform that supports `make`, or you can manually script it yourself calling the correct `avr-gcc` and `avr-g++` commands. You can check the output of the IDE for what those are.

The second part is done, usually, using `avrdude` - again see the output of the IDE for the correct command format.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. Also can I package only the required files/folders from the Arduino IDE into my software (without any license issues)?